# How to select keyframe in tool mode?

Tags: godot, gdscript

Is there anyway to select keyframes in tool mode like we do with mouse?
I have a lot of key frames and need to automate the selection process

Unselected:
[image]

Selected with mouse:
[image]

Comment: I have managed to read the current animation and time. You could, for example, select a time and click a button, select another time and click a button, and have your tool understand that as a range. With the animation name and the selected animation player, you can manipulate it. To update the animation panel you can deselect and re-select the animation player. Is that useful? Selecting the keys directly might be possible, but not straightforward and subject to break from version to version of Godot. How do you want to tell your tool what keys to select? And then what are you doing with them?

Comment: @Theraot nvm I've managed to figure out a work around but could you tell me how to reflect changes in animationPlayer after I've changed the keyframe by `track_set_key_time` ?

Comment: As I said, deselect and re-select the animation player, you can do that with `EditorSelection` which you get from the `EditorInterface` which you get from an `EditorPlugin`. I believe you need to let a frame pass before selecting the animation player again. Edit: to be fair, the animation player might not be selected to begin with, so you might want to select, de-select, select, de-select.

Comment: is there no way the changes will be reflected directly? I tried using `property_list_changed_notify()`

Comment: Nope. That works for the inspector panel. But the animation panel do not expose any of that for scripting. It is wrote like an `EditorPlugin`, just like one we could write. And I guess they didn't think somebody might want to manipulate it form code. We could go the proposal & pull request route, but if we want it today, it will be hacking around it.

Comment: @Theraot so there is no way to modify it by code and we would manually have to select and deselect?

Comment: You can hack around it, monkey patch it a bit. The editor has its own scene tree, and we can manage to get the `Control` that make up the animation panel. So, in theory, what you ask in the question is possible. We can, for example, emit their signals and hopefully it reacts as if the player was clicking them. That after we figured out the correct `Control`. But we cannot access the reference it has to the animation player, and it does not expose any function for "hey, update!", or anything like that. I suppose we could also make our own animation panel, but that is way too much more work.